# clean all cells containing no formula in a worksheet using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to clean all cells *dose not* containing a **formula**.

```
Sub DoNotContainClearCells()


Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim ContainWord As String

'What range ?
  Set rng = Worksheets("Datenbasis").Range("A5:Z100")

'What I am looking for?
  ContainWord = "="


  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then cell.Clear
  Next cell

End Sub
```

But I get the run time error 1004 and just the first column is removed. How can I treat this error? Is there any better way to delete cells from a sheet which dose not contain a formula?

Comment: `rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub DoNotContainClearCells()    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets("Datenbasis").Range("A5:Z100")
    rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Clear
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If you wish to clear cells **not** containing formulas then:

```
 Sub DoNotContainClearCells()    
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Worksheets("Datenbasis").Range("A5:Z100")
        rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Clear
    End Sub
```

will leave the formula cells alone!.

Comment: That should be solution but I need '
    rng.Cells.SpecialCells(**Not**  xlCellTypeFormulas).Clear' I have to clear every cell which does not contain a formula?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below

```
Sub DoNotContainClearCells()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    'What range ?
    Set rng = Worksheets("Datenbasis").Range("A5:Z100")
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
      If Not cell.HasFormula Then cell.Clear
    Next cell
End Sub
```